# Residual Analysis For Plots

Tags: regression, time-series

[image]

Based on my graphs can you please tell me if I am correct in my residual analysis?

- the variance is not constant since the residuals all seem to be near each other (i am having trouble here - not sure if i am interpreting the variance correctly)
- it is normally distributed
- independent since no pattern
- the outliers are 17, 18 and 5

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the variance, it doesn't seem to be getting larger or smaller systematically, hence I'd say there's homoskedasticity. You can do a heteroskedasticity test for that (White's test).

Seems to be normally distributed, you can do a test for normality too (Komlogorov-Smirnov test with normal distribution or Jarque-Bera test).

They look $iid$ since there doesn't seem to be heteroskedasticity and there doesn't seem to be any serial correlation between residuals. You can test for autocorrelation too (Box-Pierce or Ljung-Box test).

Lastly, it does seem that those 3 points are farther than the rest. Assuming a standard normal distribution they seem to be about 2 standard deviations away from the mean. I don't know if you'd consider that 'outlier' or not.

It might make sense to also show the response-feature plot too and the regression equation (and the DGP if there is one).